# /bin/bash not executing any commands

Tags: command-line, bash, macos

I set `/bin/bash` as my default shell like this:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

But it doesn't work when I open a new terminal tab. If you type any command, e.g. `ls`, no output is printed.

Likewise if I simply run `/bin/bash` from a working shell it behaves the same way.

My current shell is `/bin/sh`.

I'm trying to change my shell to bash because the current shell (`/bin/sh`) doesn't execute neither `~/.bashrc` nor `~/.bash_profile` for some reason, although it appears to be bash too:

```
$ /bin/sh --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc
```

I used to use zsh together with oh-my-zsh but it was unacceptably slow, so I'm switching back.

I used bash before that. Both of those files I mentioned were executing at that time (I didn't change the configuration).

Comment: what happens if you use /bin/ls ?

Comment: @fd0 Nothing, same as if I run `ls`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the culprit:

```
if [ -f $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion ]; then
  source $(brew --prefix)/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

These lines in my ~/.bashrc were causing bash to hang up on startup and it wasn't executing any commands as a result. Commenting them out solved the issue.

Apparently, there is some error in that script (it's part of Homebrew's `bash-completion` package).